# Cannot easily kill child processes started with bash

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, signals

In general I find child processes to be a nightmare - if I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

( proc_one ) &
( proc_two ) &

wait
```

if i ctrl-C this script, they still running the background and interrupt whatever I typing in terminal. I end up just having to close the terminal.

Is there a pattern that can be used to easily kill the child processes with the terminal?

Comment: Something like `kill %1` is usually enough.

Comment: Issue `kill %1` for the first, `kill %2` for the next and so on.

Comment: Are you really starting them with `( proc_one arg ... ) &` ? That runs a subshell in the background, and that subshell is running the script. So you are trying to kill a shell, not your own command. Shells tend to protect themselves against Ctrl-C. Maybe run the commands as `proc_one arg ... &`.

Comment: Yes, really running as a subshell, and maybe that's part of the problem but the subshell has a purpose here (for my use cases). So the question in this case is specifically about subshell subprocs

Comment: With those subshells active, I need no `trap` and no killer function. Ctrl-C immediately kills my zzOne script, both the subshells, and both the zzTwo instances. There must be something else going on here.

Answer (score 3):

Several options are available to fix this.

First, you can ignore the output they send to the terminal.  But if that's too disruptive, you can tell the terminal to stop accepting it with the command `stty tostop`

Second, you can kill these jobs.  Use the command `ps t` to find them and then kill by pid.

If there's too much output in the window, you can open another window and kill them from there.  (But then plain `ps t` won't work, you have to give the t option the name of the tty for the other window.)  Or use tostop to stop the output and then kill them.

An alternative would be to modify the script to take care of this.
When the script starts each process, it can record each process id with `$!` and save it in a variable.  Then the script can trap ctrl-c, and when that happens, it can itself kill the two jobs before honoring the ctrl-c and exiting.

Comment: there's no easy way to attach them to parent process (the script), and kill everything with Ctrl-C?

Comment: If the script backgrounded the processes and you killed the script, then the processes are orphaned and there's no way (as far as I know) to reattach to them.  Let me add an alternative to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is zzOne:

```
#! /bin/bash

Killer () {
    printf 1>&2 '\n.. Killing %s' "${Pids[@]}"
    kill -SIGKILL "${Pids[@]}"
}
trap 'Killer' SIGINT

./zzTwo 5 4 & Pids+=( "${!}" )  
./zzTwo 3 7 & Pids+=( "${!}" )

wait
printf 1>&2 '\n.. %s exits\n' "${$}"
```

This is zzTwo (emulates your proc_xxx, with different intervals):

```
#! /bin/bash

for (( j = 0; j < "${1}"; j++ )); do
    printf 1>&2 'Pid %d at %(%T)T\n' "${$}" -1
    sleep "${2}"
done

printf 1>&2 'Pid %d exits at %(%T)T\n' "${$}" -1
```

And the test:

```
$ ./zzOne
Pid 10951 at 22:35:28
Pid 10952 at 22:35:28
Pid 10951 at 22:35:32
Pid 10952 at 22:35:35
Pid 10951 at 22:35:36
^C
.. Killing 10951
.. Killing 10952
.. 10950 exits
$
```

A little verbose, but you could `source` the Killer function and trap into multiple scripts.

Comment: Very nice example!